# modify top element in queue

Tags: java, queue

So how can I modify the first element in a queue?

I am working on an assignment where I may or may not add to the queue each time the loop runs. If something is added, it is randomly assigned a number between one and five.

Once something is added, I need to then update the top object each time the loop runs by decrementing by one. Once the object become zero, I will then remove that object.

I pretty much have it all figured out except how to modify/update the top object.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you have.

Comment: I don't have any code for what I am asking about because I don't know how to do it, at all.  All of the other stuff I mentioned, I know how to do.  The only thing I don't know how to do is to decrease the value of the top element in a queue by one.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: any idea which type of object you are going to use for the queue?  If you are going to use LinkedList, then "getFirst()" method should give you the first element.  I am little confused as you are saying you want top element in the queue.  Are you trying to achieve stack or queue?

Comment: The type of object is an integer and yes, it is a queue.  I suppose I should say front rather than top, but either way, I just need to know how to change the value of the first element in a queue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `Queue<T>` [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), this is not possible. It offers a way to put elements onto the queue and a way to take them from the queue, but imposes no restrictions on where these are put in or taken from. This is left to the specific implementations. For a linearly ordered queue, like you are talking about, you should look at the `Deque<T>` [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), which lets you add to and remove from either end of the queue. Alternatively, you can use a specific queue implementation like `LinkedList<T>`, which happens to also be a `List<T>` and allows you to `set` the element at a particular offset.